# Websocket ClientEndpoint OnMessage-method not called when large String (length 20000) is sent

Tags: java, string, websocket, client

1) Using javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint and javax.websocket.OnMessage with JavaSE-1.8

2) Server (built with Annotations) sends String with length 20000:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class MyEndpoint {

  @OnMessage
  public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText( "eg String with length 20000 .... ... ..." );
  }
}
```

3) Client sends request and should receive String from server (example just receives):

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class Receiver {

  @OnMessage
  public void processMessage(String message, Session session) {
     System.out.println("Message received: " + message );
  }
}
```

But:
No Message is received by client. Shorter strings eg length 500 work.
No exception is raised at server (if try-catch used).
So - the sent string with Length 20000 disappears without any error !

A browser which sends the request to the server receives the string from the server and everything works, so problem has to be at client.

Also the implementation org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient receives the String from the server.

I also tried to set MaxTextMessageBufferSize with

```
session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(25000);
```

Where is the bug?

Where do i have to report this bug to get a working client for larger strings?

The implementation of javax.websocket is pretty nice with its session-IDs and i do not want to wrap org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient just because of this single bug in javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a server configuration issue or bug.

*(Hard to narrow down how to help, as you didn't tell us what kind of server you are using)*

Most modern `javax.websocket` servers can handle multi-megabyte message sizes with ease.

These work great:

- Jetty 9.2.x+
- Tomcat 8.x+
- Wildfly/JBoss 8.x+

All of those have excellent websocket support and configuration options.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into my issue!
As you pointed out "Wildfly 8.x+" seems to work fine.

Comment: Because there are no problems using a differen Client-Implementation (i tried with org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient and it works fine). Therefor my conclusion would be, that the problem is sitting within the javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint implementation itself.

Any idea how to debug this, when the receiving function javax.websocket.OnMessage never gets called and no exception is raised on the server or client side.